# Moving to middle of huge file in Vim or gVim

Tags: vim, shortcut

Is there a Vim command to move to the middle of a huge file without calculating `(total lines/2)` and using `j`? Something like `zz`, `zt`, or `zb`, which moves only around the current screen?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use one of the features that vim borrowed from [elvis](http://elvis.the-little-red-haired-girl.org/): it accepts a percentage of the file directly.  For example, typing

```
50%
```

jumps to the middle of the file.

In vim, if you enter

```
:h up-down-motions
```

that leads to the [section](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#up-down-motions) describing the feature:

```
{count}%    Go to {count} percentage in the file, on the first
            non-blank in the line |linewise|.  To compute the new
            line number this formula is used:
                ({count} * number-of-lines + 99) / 100
            See also 'startofline' option.  {not in Vi}
```

Comment: `:50%` does not work (using VIM 7.4), but `50%` (no colon, this is "not an editor command") works great.  You can go straight to that part of the help with `:help N%` rather than having to navigate through `up-down-motions`.  Nice tip!

Comment: I'm having trouble getting `autocmd BufEnter * 50%` to work :(